# Вопросы по адаптации сайта

Tags: css

Всем привет, чтобы сайт выглядел одиннаково на разных диагоналях и разрешениях в css стоит лучше задавать размеры в % или использовать media? Я понимаю, что их вероятно комбинируют, однако в таком случае мне не понятно как. Например: есть кнопка, если я использую media, то ей размеры задавать в px или %? Еще хотел узнать на счет шрифта: его тоже в px или %?

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что вы в самом деле хотите, чтобы сайт выглядел везде одинаково. На 4K-мониторах будет слишком крупно, на мобилках будет слишком мелко

Comment: Извиняюсь за некорректный вопрос. Я имел ввиду, чтобы элементы находились на определенных местах, в зависимости от диагонали и разрешения. Так же я хочу уточнить, если в media задавать все размеры элементов в px, то не будет ли такой проблемы, как "разъезжающиеся элементы" при масштабировании сайта в браузере (ctrl + колесико)?

Comment: Пиксель масштабируется вместе со всем масштабом, а единицы измерения выбирайте по задаче в эависимости от того, какое конкретно поведение вы хотите (лепить всё подряд в пикселях или всё подряд в процентах скорее всего бессмысленно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Тема

Вопрос о том, как задавать размеры элементов и шрифтов на сайте, зависит от конкретных требований и дизайна проекта.

---

### Описание

Использование процентов (%) для задания размеров элементов может быть полезным, если вам нужно, чтобы элементы масштабировались пропорционально при изменении размеров окна браузера или на разных устройствах. Например, вы можете использовать % для задания ширины блока или кнопки, чтобы они автоматически адаптировались к разным разрешениям экрана.

С другой стороны, использование медиа-запросов (media queries) позволяет вам более точно контролировать стили на разных разрешениях экрана. Вы можете определить разные стили для разных диапазонов ширины экрана и применять их при необходимости. Например, вы можете задать фиксированный размер кнопки в пикселях (px) для маленьких экранов и использовать % или другие единицы измерения для больших экранов.

Относительно шрифтов, также можно использовать как пиксели (px), так и проценты (%). Опять же, выбор зависит от ваших потребностей и предпочтений. Использование % позволяет шрифту масштабироваться вместе с элементом, к которому он применяется, в то время как фиксированный размер в пикселях может быть полезен для точного контроля над внешним видом шрифта.

---

### Итог

Комбинация использования процентов и медиа-запросов может быть наиболее эффективным подходом. Вы можете задавать размеры элементов в %, чтобы они масштабировались пропорционально, и использовать медиа-запросы для определения более специфичных стилей на разных разрешениях экрана.